# will AppLifecycleState active in whole applife or the page I use it

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }
  
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      debugPrint("AppLifecycleState.resumed");
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      debugPrint("AppLifecycleState.paused");
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      debugPrint("AppLifecycleState.detached");
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      debugPrint("AppLifecycleState.inactive");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
}
```

**this is a demoPage above,I wonder if the didChangeAppLifecycleState() method will print on any time I change app state,or just print when I change app state from DemoPage**